# Условия в генераторе списков

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему первый вариант проходит без ошибок, а второй выводит ошибку? Я вчера видел что и такой и такой вариант канает, но не могу найти ту статью. Будьте добры, объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Согласно правилам сайта надо: а) размещать код в виде текста; б) включать один вопрос в запрос. По поводу функций просьба создать отдельный запрос.

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = [x for x in range(10) if x > 5]

# В этом случае все элементы меньше или равные 5 будут пропущены

# А ошибка у Вас здесь, бы забыли значение подмены поставить
#               VVVVV 
b = [x if x > 5 else None for x in range(10)]
# В этом варианте все элементы меньше или равные 5 будут заменены на None
```

---

По просьбе из коммента, но без лямбды ибо нафиг не нужна

```py
c = [x for x in range(10) if x % 2 == 0]
```

---

Lambda с фильтром

```py
# так чтобы понятно
d = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, range(10)))
# так, чтобы по "феншую"
d = list(filter(lambda x: not x % 2, range(10)))
```

---

На правах изврата

```py
criteria = lambda x: x > 5
c = [x for x in range(10) if criteria(x)]
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можете подсказать почему в lambda не работает первый вариант? Например код lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0.Как сделать анонимную функцию без else?

Comment: @28Lucky, `lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0 else None` Вы скажите что из чего в оконцовке получить хотите

Comment: @28Lucky, вангую вам нужно что-то типа `a = list(filter(lambda x: x > 5, range(10)))`

Answer (score 1):

Во втором случае вы пытаетесь использовать **тернарный оператор**, но он по определению должен состоять из **трёх** частей, и конкретно в питоне он выглядит как `значение_если_истина if условие else значение_если_ложь`.

В первом же случае `if` относится к конструкции **списочное сокращение** и там никакого `else` даже и не предусмотрено, поэтому там всё корректно.